# C#.Net Winforms program can't write to Adafruit Fona

Tags: c#, winforms, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I have written a programme in C#.Net Winforms (I'm new to programming) that runs on a Raspberry Pi.

Connected to the Pi is an Afadruit Fona (Sim800L).

I am using the following library: https://github.com/PervasiveDigital/SimComDotNet.git, to communicate with the Fona.

The problem that I am having is that when it tries to perform a single command on the fona, the thread crashes. No matter what command I perform on the fona; I've tried loads, it always crashes after the first attempt.

In the class below that I have written, it crashed immediately after the UseExternalAudio command.

Here's the code:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using Molarity.Hardare.AdafruitFona;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace FAS
{
    public class call
    {
        private BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        private string number;
        public bool open_call=false, close_call=false;

        public call(string path)
        {
            number = ReadAllText(path + @"/number");
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            if (bw.IsBusy != true) bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort("/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
            FonaDevice fona = new FonaDevice(port);
            fona.UseExternalAudio=true;
            while (true)
            {
                if (open_call) 
                {
                    fona.PhoneCall(number);
                    open_call=false;
                }
                if (close_call)
                {
                    fona.HangUp();
                    close_call=false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help!?

Comment: What means "crash"? What exception? Would it work from Windows with .Net instead of Mono?

Comment: Can't run in Win as the library is for Pi. Compiles in Linux using mono and I put the exe on the Pi. After it successfully performs the first Fona command, the thread stops, assuming it errors but mono won't output errors from the background worker. My best guess is that I am using serial ports or the Fona library wrong as they are both new to me, I've been coding for a few months now.

Comment: Again - what exception?

Comment: Apologies, as I mentioned i am fairly new to programming so I'm not sure how well I can answer this question. I haven't been able to get any feedback from the point of error so my understanding as that if there were any execptions this is the point at which I should see them?